# Problems Understanding Async Task C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

Hello everyone and thanks for the help in advance.  I am working in .Net Core C# along with the Twilio api.  I am using one of the Twilio examples on a controller that looks like this:

```
public async Task<TwiMLResult> InboundSMS(SmsRequest request, int numMedia)
    { return TwiML(messagingResponse); }
```

Intellisense tells me "The async method lacks await operators and will run synchronously.  Consider using the await operator to await non-blocking api calls."  The controller is an endpoint called by the Twilio api.  The endpoint in turn processes the posted data and then performs various business logic routines.  To be honest, I'm really not sure what this is telling me and I have no idea how (or even if) I should correct this.  Also, since there will be multiple business logic routines spawned from this endpoint, so long running, I want to understand what I am doing.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh, but if you do not understand that error message, you need to spend an hour or two understanding async/await before using it, otherwise you encounter even more serious problems with their misuse. Even seasoned programmers don't always get async/await right. The message is telling you that the correct syntax for `return TwiML(messagingResponse)` is `return await TwiML(messagingResponse)`. If that gives you an error about no `GetAwaiter` then the _TwiML_ method is not async and neither should your _InboundSMS_ method be.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not harsh at all.  I simply needed to have the conviction in knowing the error message return await TwiML(messagingResponse) was telling me there was no GetAwaiter.  Bad code sample, but I should have known better.  Thanks again.

Comment: The first message, _lacks await operators and will run synchronously_ is really just a warning/reminder that you might have forgotten the `await` keyword. That said, if the `TwiML` method is not asynchronous, you can safely ignore the warning and leave the `async` keyword there as well. It's confusing and sloppy but sometimes necessary when using async methods mixed with non-async methods.

Answer (score 0):

The two correct answers for this are:

1. Remove the Task from the method:

   `public TwiMLResult InboundSMS(SmsRequest request, int numMedia) { return TwiML(messagingResponse);  }`
2. Make the call async by using AWAIT:

   `public async Task<TwiMLResult> InboundSMS(SmsRequest request, int numMedia) { return await TwiML(messagingResponse);  }`

Which method you choose depends on whether 'TwiML' is truly async

Comment: You missed 3) `Task.FromResult`. Sometimes you are forced to implement an interface that expects a task.

Comment: Agreed, it is "an" answer; but. I purposely didn't suggest the Task.FromResult because its typically bad practice and a sign that something needs rethinking somewhere